# Downloading repository doesn't work

Tags: updates, repository

I have a problem when I am downloading and trying to install few things eg: `mtp-tools`. It's telling me that it's going to add 265 K on my disk, I press `YES` and then it stays on  waiting for headers( I changed from main server to UK server,  but it didn't make any difference).

Any idea guys?

Comment: In future, do not use the 'bug-reporting' tag.  This place isnt for reporting bugs, its for diagnosing problems.  Have patience with your problem, as it may just be a huge header for that repository (including all the information about the repo, etc. for apt-cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First confirm that you are able to browse other websites.
2. Then, Run this commands:

   sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists{,bakjune4}; 
   sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/partial{,bakjune4}; 
   sudo apt-get update; 
   sudo apt-get upgrade;

**Note:**
In any case you can revert to your current situation by using followiing commands:

- sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/;
- sudo mv /var/lib/apt/list{bakjune4,};
- sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/partial{bakjune4,};